# Yii2 Set page title from component view

Tags: php, yii2

I have page, for example, **/about**.

In page's view i may set page title: `$this->title = "abc"` - it works ok.

Also i have Header component in /components with his own view /components/views/Header.php

How could I change my page title from my component's view?
`$this->title` does not work because I'm in component's view, not page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you are calling your component, but to change the title you need to specify you want to change the current view.

Here is an example, in the view add something like (or use any method you already used but make sure you insert the view as a parameter):

```
MyComponent::changeTitle($this);
```

And in your component (whatever method you want to do this):

```
public static function changeTitle($view)
{
    $view->title = 'changed';
}
```

If this is not related with your situation, please add an example of the view and the component so we can understand better what is the scenario.

Comment: I've simplified the problem - i have layout "main.php"
in this layout i'm setting $this->title = "test title"; And it d't work - title still empty. When i do the same thing in controller's view file - it works fine.

Comment: In your layout, you must have the html code that calls the title, something like `<title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>`. You need to change the title before this line. I just made a test here with no problems.

Comment: Yes, figured it out - i've placed code after title tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Embed the page object into the component. Then change the properties of the page object through the aggregation composition.

The component class would read something like...

```
class MyComponent extends Component
{
    private $pageObject;
    public $title;

    public function __construct(yii\web\View $view)
    {
        $this->pageObject = $view;
    }

    // this would change the title of the component
    public function setTitle(string $newTitle)
    {
        $this->title = $newTitle;
    }

    public function changePageTitle(string $newTitle)
    {
        $this->pageObject->title = $newTitle;
    }
}
```

Where, if you're in a view and you want to use your component in that view, you can instantiate it using

```
$comp = new MyComponent($this);
// where `$this` is the current page object
```

Now, from the component scope, `$this->title = 'bleh';` would change the title of the component while `$this->changePageTitle('bleh');` would change the page's title.